# Как правильно реализовать методы в классах?

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть 5 классов, которые должны содержать различные наборы методов. Четыре метода идентичны для всех классов, остальные варьируются. Одинаковые во всех пяти классах методы вынес в абстрактный класс, от которого они наследуют эти методы. Различающиеся методы расписываются в каждом классе индивидуально.

Но среди этих остальных методов есть один, который также должен быть идентичен для всех классов кроме одного.

Собственно, как с ним быть: просто описать этот метод одинаково в только тех четырех классах из пяти, где он должен быть или есть еще варианты? Просто не хочется добавлять его в общий абстрактный класс, от которого все наследуются, и в одном классе наследнике переопределять этот метод, выбрасывая NotImplementedException или NotSupportedException. Как реализуются такие случаи с точки зрения ООП?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A
{
  public void M1() {}
  public void M2() {}
  public void M3() {}
  public void M4() {}
}

public class B : A
{
  public void M5() {}
}

public class C : A
{
  ...
}

public class D1 : B
{
  ...
}
public class D2 : B
{
  ...
}
public class D3 : B
{
  ...
}
public class D4 : B
{
  ...
}
```

Пять конечных классов: `C`, `D1`, `D2`, `D3`,`D4`.